How to derive this relation? (Ashcroft & Mermin, "Solid State Physics")
I am following Ashcroft & Mermin, "Solid State Physics". In 33th chapter, they talk about ferromagnetic Hamiltonian
$$
H=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R}'} J(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R}')\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{R})\cdot\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{R}') \tag{33.4}
$$
$\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{R})$ is spin operator at site $\mathbf{R}$. The ground state $|0\rangle$'s energy is $E_0=-1/2S^2\sum_{\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R}'} J(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R}')$, Eq. (33.11).
They talk about first excited state $|\mathbf{R}\rangle$ which is given with the help of ladder operators $\mathbf{S}_\pm(\mathbf{R})$:
$$
|\mathbf{R}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2S}} \mathbf{S}_-(\mathbf{R})|0\rangle \tag{33.19}
$$
and Hamiltonian in terms of ladder operators is:
$$
H=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R}'} J(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R}')\mathbf{S}_-(\mathbf{R}') \mathbf{S}_+(\mathbf{R}) -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R}'} J(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R}')\mathbf{S}_z(\mathbf{R}) \mathbf{S}_z(\mathbf{R}') \tag{33.9}
$$
They derive two identities:
1.
$$
\mathbf{S}_-(\mathbf{R'}) \mathbf{S}_+(\mathbf{R})|\mathbf{R}\rangle=2S|\mathbf{R'}\rangle \tag{33.20}
$$
2.
$$
\mathbf{S}_z(\mathbf{R'}) |\mathbf{R}\rangle=S|\mathbf{R}\rangle;\ \ \ \ \text{for}\ \ \ \  \mathbf{R}'\ne\mathbf{R}  \\
\mathbf{S}_z(\mathbf{R'}) |\mathbf{R}\rangle=(S-1)|\mathbf{R}\rangle;\ \ \ \ \text{for}\ \ \ \ \mathbf{R}'=\mathbf{R}  \tag{33.21}
$$
then they say that due to these identites, the action of $H$ is
$$
H|\mathbf{R}\rangle =E_0|\mathbf{R}\rangle + S\sum_{\mathbf{R}'} J(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{R}')\left\{|\mathbf{R}\rangle-|\mathbf{R}'\rangle\right\} \tag{33.22}
$$
How to derive Eq. (33.22)?
